# Issues duplicating display on Windows 7 to Toshiba TV

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I had basically the same issue as here: [Can no longer duplicate display to external monitor on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/332689/can-no-longer-duplicate-display-to-external-monitor-on-windows-7) only I have a Lenovo T430.

I'm using a DVI to HDMI cable to display my laptop on my Toshiba TV, and I have had no issues with duplication until today. Up until today, it's been an automatic process of plugging the cable in and having it self duplicate, but today it will only extend displays for some reason.

Win+P or Fn+F7 -> duplicate does not work, it resizes my computer screen and displays nothing on the TV. The native resolution on my laptop is 1600x900 and the native resolution on my TV is 1920x1080. I've tried restarting with the cable in/out to no avail.

I've also tried opening the NVIDIA control panel, going down to Set up multiple displays. Then I right click display 2 (my TV) and click clone with -> 1, this merges 1 and 2 into a box and looks right, but then when I click apply it ends up displaying only on my TV, and unchecking my laptop display all together. If I right click display 1 and click clone with 2, I get the reverse result. Display only on my laptop and my TV becomes unchecked. Any help?